# How do I set global events to false when using jquery ajax shorthand?

Tags: jquery, ajax, global, shorthand

How do I set global events to false using ajax shorthand.

```
$.get( "ajax/test.html", function( data ) {
   $( ".result" ).html( data );
   alert( "Load was performed." );
});
```

Where should I put global: false ?

```
$.ajax({
   url: "test.html",
   global: false,
   // ...
});
```

I add in the following but not working.

```
$.get( "ajax/test.html", {global: false}, function( data ) {
   $( ".result" ).html( data );
   alert( "Load was performed." );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up inside ajaxSetup like so :

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  global : false,
  .....
});
```

But this will affected any others ajax request as this for the whole ajax configurations. Prior to `jQuery 3.0`, you can setup like original ajax form. See this [Link](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/#jQuery-get-settings).
By the way you can change the default properties by using `$.ajaxSend()`. Intercept the request before send. Assume you're calling the request like so :

```
$.get( "ajax/test.html", function( data ) {
 ......
 ......
});
```

Then inside `$.ajaxSend()`, we can target only specified request by using  :

```
// ajaxSend must be attached to document
$(document).ajaxSend( function ( e, jqxhr, setting ) {
   // if the request same with the above source/path
   if ( setting.url == "ajax/test.html" ) {
     // set global to false
     setting.global = false;
   }
});
```

If you're doing like this, `$.ajaxSetup()` won't need anymore. Therefore, if you think this step is quite long or not suitable, then just use `$.ajax()`.

Comment: but I just want to target particular ajax request.